# Schur decomposition of an $n-$by$-n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, schur-decomposition

$(\lambda, x)$ is a simple (with multiplicity 1) eigenpair of $A\in \mathbb C_n$ with $x^Hx=1$, $H$ denotes Hermitian.

Use Schur decomposition to show that there exists a nonsingular matrix $(x\ \ X)$ such that
$$
(x\ X)^{-1}A(x\ X)=\left(\matrix{\lambda \ \ \ \ 0\\ \ 0\ \ \  M}\right)
$$
where $M\in\mathbb C_{n-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose for some invertible $P$ we have
$$
P^{-1}AP = \pmatrix{\lambda&b^H\\ 0&M}
$$
for some $b\in\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ and $M\in M_{n-1}(\mathbb{C})$. For any vector $u\in\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$, we have
$$
\pmatrix{1&-u^H\\ 0&I}\pmatrix{\lambda&b^H\\ 0&M}\pmatrix{1&u^H\\ 0&I}
=\pmatrix{\lambda&b^H - u^H(M-\lambda I)\\ 0&M}.
$$
Since $\lambda$ is *not* an eigenvalue of $M$ (why?), we can choose $u$ such that $b^H - u^H(M-\lambda I)=0$ (why?).

Comment: $\lambda$ is simple so  $\det(M-\lambda I)\neq 0$. So $(M-\lambda I)$ is nonsingular and hence we can solve the $u$ for any $b$. Right? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Falang Yes, it's crucial that $M-\lambda I$ is nonsingular.